# A function inside a dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I would like to write a function inside a dict:

```
A = {
 'a': 6, 
 'b': 3,
 'operation': def myfunc(x, y): 
                # do many things here, I can't use a lambda x,y: ...
                return x + y
}
```

but this doesn't work. **Why? Is there a way to make it work?**

*Remark: The following solution works, but I would really prefer to write the function* inside *the dict:*

```
def myfunc(x, y): return x + y

A = {
 'a': 6, 
 'b': 3,
 'operation': myfunc
}
```

Comment: Use `lambda`: `lambda x, y: x + y` There's no reason to do this though.

Comment: @vaultah : the function is too big and uses local variable, I can't use a `lambda`.

Comment: Why inside the dict?

Comment: @Basj Python does not support the thing you are trying to do. But you already know how to do it, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Basj: then you can't. Function definitions are *statements*, so they have to be on their own line. They can not be inserted into expressions. Lambda's are expressions, so they *can* be used that way.

Comment: If you want your function to only be accessed throught the dictionary, you could do a function `get_weird_dict()` that creates and return  the dictionary, in which the `myfunc` function is declared locally, and hence inaccessible outside `get_weird_dict()`

Answer (score 6):

> but this doesn't work. **Why?**

Function definitions using `def` are [(compound) *statements*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html). Statements are the [top-level component](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html) in the Python language grammar. Statements can contain [*expressions*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html), but expressions can not contain statements, only other expressions.

A dictionary literal is [an expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries), so it can only contain other expressions, and not a `def` statement.

> **Is there a way to make it work?**

Your options are to use expressions. Either a `lambda` or a reference to a function you defined earlier, (as you discovered).

`lamdba`s are expressions, they can only contain more expressions, which implicitly produces the return value. You can't use things like `return` or assignments, because those are statements, so they are quite limited. If a `lambda` can't do what you want, your only remaining option is to do what you already did, store a reference to the function object.